# Authenticate or Register w/ Spring Social Oauth + Qt C++ App

Tags: spring, qt, oauth, spring-security, jhipster

I have a [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io) web-app based on Spring w/ [Spring Social](http://jhipster.github.io/security/) (Oauth2) for user authentication, I now want to extend the authentication / registration process to a C++ Desktop application built in QT. Ideally using the same user-registration / user-authentication already generated.

The flow in jHipster / Spring-Social is pretty standard for webapps, but I'm not positive on the desktop side of things the best way to go.

**Jhipster / Spring-Social**

1. User Clicks "Social Link" user-link
2. User Authenticates to Social network (Facebook for example)
3. OAuth posts back a valid token as a request parameter, user is registered, or authenticated by app.
4. User's browser is 'cookied' with their session (Spring Security - Stateful)

I've looked at the options for OAuth with Qt, and there is a flow [o2](https://github.com/pipacs/o2) which pop's a browser, authenticates the user and collects the postback from OAuth with a valid token (doesn't register a user, etc.) just securely stores it.

*I'm wondering if there are any pitfalls in modifying o2 to:*

1. redirect the user's browser to my jHipster application's registration / authentication flow
2. collect the valid spring security cookie
3. cache it use it to make requests other authenticated requests to my web-services

**Alternatively:**

1. Collect the user's OAuth token from in Qt from o2,
2. pass a registration / authentication service endpoint in my app and collect a valid session cookie, and store it locally

I'm thinking the second way is the way to go, because I don't want to fiddle with getting a cookie from a browser when that's not it's intended procedure.

If I manually post the validated token to Spring Security (as a way to identify the user I want to authenticate to Spring Security is there a way to do this with Spring Security? Or should I simply look up the user based on parsed information in their OAuth postback?

Thanks

PS. *[jHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/security/) has implementations for OAuth2 Authentication / Stateless-token authentication (the later of which I always assumed was more appropriate for desktop based clients), but I don't want to reinvent the wheel as far as try to haphazardly merge the stateless-spring security with another methodology!*